# Managing HyperV Server 2012R2 from Windows 10 powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have trouble managing hosts running HyperV Server 2012R2 (the standalone HyperV installation) through PowerShell on Windows 10. While I can connect to them via Hyper-V-Manager in Windows 10 and manage them just fine, when I try running powershell commands such as:

```
Get-VMHost <HyperVHostName>
```

or

```
Get-VMReplication -ComputerName <HyperVHostName>
```

Powershell returns

> The Hyper-V module used in this Windows PowerShell session cannot be used for remote management of the server. Load a compatible version of the Hyper-V module, or use Powershell remoting to connect directly to the remote server.

The documentation the error message further points to leads to the basic remote management docs for Hyper-V 2012R2 found here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846767(v=ws.11).aspx

The powershell commands work fine with Hyper-V Server 2016 as well as Windows Server 2016. Since I don't want to use PowerShell remoting to connect to each machine individually with a PowerShell session, I'd like to know what I can do to get managing HyperV Server 2012R2 from Windows 10 Powershell to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this address your issue?  If so, will post it up as an answer. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2015/11/16/why-are-there-two-hyper-v-powershell-modules-in-windows-10/

Comment: Tried it just now, if I load the 1.1 Hyper-V module with "Import-Module -name Hyper-V -RequiredVersion 1.1", I am able to manage both the 2012R2 and the 2016 hosts. Thanks for the tip, and please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the version of the Hyper-V cmdlets you need, e.g. `Import-Module Hyper-V -RequiredVersion 1.1`

Windows remote management tools have typically been able to manage the same version server as where you ran the tool, plus two versions back.  Internally it's referred to as "N-2" support.
The Hyper-V cmdlets don't do this directly, but they provided additional versions of their module that can be selected at need.  Ben Armstrong's blog discusses it here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2015/11/16/why-are-there-two-hyper-v-powershell-modules-in-windows-10/

You can see a general support list for Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx